# Why type assigning works differently when type is actual type vs generic type

Tags: typescript

The following code does not have any errors:

```
type C = {b: string};

class Class {
    data: C;
    constructor(data: C) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    test() {
        const hack: C & {a?: any} = this.data; //no error
    }
}
```

But if I use generic type instead of actual type code does not compile:

```
class Class<C> {
    data: C;
    constructor(data: C) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    test() {
        const hack: C & {a?: any} = this.data; //TS2322: Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'C & { a?: any; }'
    }
}
```

Can you explain why? In the second code snippet C can be anything. If I understand duck typing correctly **anything** should be compatible with **anything & something optional**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have not constrained the generic type `C`, which as you mentioned can be anything. In this case, 'anything' include both `undefined` and `null`. If you instantiated the class with `undefined` as the generic type, then it makes sense for the compiler to give you an error, since `undefined & {a?: any}` is a non-sensical type. Same thing for the types `null`, `never` and `unknown`

If the generic were constrained to be `C extends object`, `C extends string`, etc, then the compiler error goes away